# KVC - Filter Sets

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, key-value-coding

I have a simple data model (Core Data), but here is a stripped down version of it:

```
Account
----------------------------------------------------
NSSet<Transaction> transactions

Transaction
----------------------------------------------------
Account  account
NSNumber amount
NSNumber type ( type ∈ ( 0->'Credit', 1->'Debit' ) )
```

I want to get an account's total balance, however, I don't want to mark a debit as a negative number. I just want it to be an amount with a type of debit.

Currently, before I added the debits in, I could get the balance via this function in Account:

```
- (NSNumber *)currentBalance
{
    return [self.transactions valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amount"];
}
```

Obviously, that will only work if I make debits negative. Is there an elegant solution here, to perhaps filter the set into credits and debits, sum those, and perform a difference? Will that maintain accuracy? I've looked into NSPredicate, but I'm not sure how exactly to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what my research has led me to:

```
- (NSNumber *)currentBalance
{
    // credits
    NSPredicate *creditPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [((Transaction *)evaluatedObject).type intValue] == kTransactionTypeCredit;
    }];

    NSSet *credits = [self.transactions filteredSetUsingPredicate:creditPredicate];

    NSDecimalNumber *totalCredits = [credits valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amount"];

    // debits
    NSPredicate *debitPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [((Transaction *)evaluatedObject).type intValue] == kTransactionTypeDebit;
    }];

    NSSet *debits = [self.transactions filteredSetUsingPredicate:debitPredicate];

    NSDecimalNumber *totalDebits = [debits valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amount"];

    // do the math
    return [totalCredits decimalNumberBySubtracting:totalDebits];
}
```

Whilst it works, it seems like an excessive amount of work. Is it the best way?

Comment: It seems like a lot of work just to use the @sum feature of KVC.

Comment: You could also add another property to your object to return the signed value and sum that instead.  Or just ditch the @sum and loop through them and add subtract accordingly?  BTW you can use the transaction type in the block signature itself and save the type cast inside the block.  (so instead of 'id evaluatedObject' just use 'Transaction *transaction')

Comment: @RoryO'Bryan: I love the recommendation of using a new property. That's brilliant. Thank you very much! Sometimes I need to take a step back and think about the simpler solutions.